# Display an IF_IXML_ELEMENT object via DISPLAY_XML_DOCUMENT

Tags: xml, abap

I have a program which displays an XML document via the function module `DISPLAY_XML_DOCUMENT` :

```
DATA(xml_document) = new cl_xml_document( ).
xml_document->parse_string( `<ROOT><city><name>Paris</name>` &&
        `<country><name>France</name><iso>FRA</iso></country>` &&
        `</city></ROOT>` ).

" Display the whole document
CALL FUNCTION 'DISPLAY_XML_DOCUMENT'
  EXPORTING
    xml_document = xml_document
  EXCEPTIONS
    OTHERS       = 1.

" Extract the country name and ISO code

DATA(element) = CAST if_ixml_element(
            xml_document->find_node( name = '/ROOT/city/country' ) ).

" Display the whole document
CALL FUNCTION 'DISPLAY_XML_DOCUMENT'
  EXPORTING
    xml_document = element
  EXCEPTIONS
    OTHERS       = 1.
```

The first call to the function module `DISPLAY_XML_DOCUMENT` displays the whole XML document:

[image]

Then the `element` object is initialized with `<country><name>France</name><iso>FRA</iso></country>`. It's of type `IF_IXML_ELEMENT`.

Alas, the display of the element does a **runtime error CX_SY_DYN_CALL_ILLEGAL_TYPE** because an object of type `CL_XML_DOCUMENT_BASE` is expected, not an element of type `IF_IXML_ELEMENT`.

How to display the `element` object via `DISPLAY_XML_DOCUMENT` ?

Comment: As getting the XML text from an `IF_IXML_ELEMENT` object is straight forward ("get content as string" method), I guess the question is about **displaying** but what do you mean by "display as an XML document", is it to display it hierarchically, one XML element per line, as it's done by the navigators, and the same as the method `DISPLAY` of the class `CL_XML_DOCUMENT`? (PS: the term "XML document" is very generic and doesn't mean the class `CL_XML_DOCUMENT` which is very rarely used in ABAP)

Comment: thank you for your answer! I'm sorry if I wasn't precise enough. But there is a function module called "Display_xml_document" but this one only works with cl_xml_documents and not if_ixml_element. I need a FM or anything like that which does the same thing as "display_xml_document".

Comment: I have rewritten your question so that it's [more precise](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for next visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Attach the element to a new empty XML document instance as follows :

```
DATA(new_xml_document) = new cl_xml_document_base( ).
new_xml_document->create_with_node( element ).

CALL FUNCTION 'DISPLAY_XML_DOCUMENT'
  EXPORTING
    xml_document = new_xml_document
  EXCEPTIONS
    OTHERS       = 1.
```

Here is the result :

[image]